# Hide an Android/iOS app and make it launchable only by url

Tags: android, ios, launching-application

I am working on an application that should communicate with my web app to retrieve some data.

So I have application A which is a web app.
There is this other application B which is Native and is not designe to access internet.

Application B connects to a device using blutooth protocol and gets data from a remote Device.

app A calls app B with its reverse url (B://callmeBack/?appName=A) 
And then app B interprets the callmeBack arg and calls A (A://?data=someData)

App A can call all pages of B (B://pageName/?data=someData)

This works fine. 
Since app B doesn't communicate with internet I want B to be hidden, so that users always use A to go to B, and B to give back data to A when A asks B.

App A can be used every where and give richer content.

How can I make B (native app) hidden and only laounchble from A for iOS and Android?

Is it something I need to add in the B AndroidManifest.xml and the equivalent in iOS ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you have two separate apps in the first place?

Comment: I will merge the two apps later. But for now I need to find a way to use the two apps : A as master, and B as slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you should remove the intent filter which is used to tell the launcher, that it should be displayed from your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Typically it looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: removing this block from AndroidManifest will make the application invisible in applications list?

Comment: Yes, this intent filter is used to tell the launcher that your application wants this Activity to be visible.